# SELECT reads 50 000 rows/s for days never INSERTS

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-migration

I am trying to normalize my database. I have broken out all redundant data and is now joining and inserting the new data. I have been porting 1 million rows at a time and that have worked well up until now. Now a million rows takes days instead of minutes, and it seam to be stuck on reading many many millions of rows and never getting to the inserting part.

I have this Query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO bbointra_normalized.entry (DATE,keyword,url,POSITION,competition,searchEngine) SELECT DATE(insDate) AS DATE,k.id AS kid ,u.id uid, POSITION, competition ,s.id AS sid FROM oldSingleTabels.tempData 
INNER JOIN bbointra_normalized.keyword k ON tempData.keyword = k.keyword
INNER JOIN bbointra_normalized.searchEngine s ON tempData.searchEngine = s.searchEngine
INNER JOIN bbointra_normalized.urlHash u ON tempData.url = u.url
GROUP BY k.id, s.id, u.id ORDER BY k.id, s.id, u.id
```

EXPLAIN:

```
    id  select_type  table     type    possible_keys                                 key           key_len  ref                             rows  Extra                                         
------  -----------  --------  ------  --------------------------------------------  ------------  -------  ----------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       s         index   (NULL)                                        searchEngine  42       (NULL)                           539  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
     1  SIMPLE       k         index   (NULL)                                        keyword       42       (NULL)                         17652  Using index; Using join buffer                
     1  SIMPLE       tempData  ref     keyword_url_insDate,keyword,searchEngine,url  keyword       767      func                             433  Using where                                   
     1  SIMPLE       u         ref     url                                           url           767      oldSingleTabels.tempData.url       1  Using index
```

SHOW INNODB STATUS:

```
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 4245, id 140024097179392, state: waiting for server activity
Number of rows inserted 26193732, updated 0, deleted 0, read 3383512394
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 39676.56 reads/s
```

SQL for entry:

```
   CREATE TABLE `entry` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `insDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `project` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `keyword` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `url` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `competition` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `serachEngine` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `unikt` (`date`,`keyword`,`position`,`serachEngine`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: How are you doing the 1M batch size? If you take the INSERT away from your insertion query so you are just left with the SELECT can you reproduce the issue selecting from the start of your data-set vs further in? If so it sounds like that constraint is the issue.

Comment: I have a table with 50M entrys and i move the fist 1M into a table called tempData, after the import i truncate that table and move the next million rows.

Comment: So it is definitely the INSERT that is causing the issue as the source data-set is in a fixed location per-iteration. Now you are N++ million rows in is the INSERT IGNORE mostly hitting existing rows or creating new ones? Also can we see the CREATE TABLE for bbointra_normalized.entry?

Comment: It it mostly inserting new ones. I added the CREATE TABLE SQL. But am starting to think that the SELECT is the problem. I think it is having a problem withe the joins :/

Comment: Are the fields on the auxiliary tables that are used in the join indexed? e.g. bbointra_normalized.keyword bbointra_normalized.searchEngine and bbointra_normalized.urlHash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many people pointed out, since this was a read problem, I broke the SELECT query down and tested the query minus one join at the time, I was expecting the huge URL table/keys to be the problem but soon found that the main problem was a corrupt table/index on the keyword table. I don't know how this could happen but after dropping and recreating that table, things magically started to work again just fine.

I later took @abasterfield's advice and added 3 more indexes to the Entry table and this sped up the select even more.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses, they are heavy to process and do not seem to add any value.

If there are indexes on table bbointra_normalized.entry, try removing these temporarily since it is a heavy process to update the indexes when inserting many rows.

Answer (score 0):

At each `INSERT`/`UPDATE` MySQL updates the indexes of your tables. And this is slow.

If you are doing a massive `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, you should disable the keys, so the index is recalculated only once, instead of for each inserted/updated row.

Here is how :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
-- Your INSERT/UPDATE statement here
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```

Comment: I will try this, but since the query never seams to be begin the insertion process, (it is reading for hours and hours)  I cant see how this could be the main problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. But then you shouldn't put the `INSERT SELECT` statement, but only the `SELECT`. Good luck.

Comment: No, I want it to INSERT, it just never happens at this point :/

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the read problem. Narrow the problem as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some indexes - every field you are linking too needs it's own index

```
ALTER TABLE `entry` ADD KEY (`keyword`);
ALTER TABLE `entry` ADD KEY (`searchEngine`);
ALTER TABLE `entry` ADD KEY (`urlHash`);
```

It looks very much like the first one of these is the one needed the most

Comment: If you're getting all the data (there's no WHERE clause) then you certainly don't _need_ indexes.

Comment: Yes you seam to be right.. something is off with the keyword index. It dose have a index but it dose not act like it.. BRB

Comment: @Ben It's for the INNER JOINs not for a WHERE constraint (as the isn't one)

Comment: On your CREATE TABLE there is no index on keyword

Comment: I understand that @abasterfield, however, the OP is selecting everything in all the tables, because there's no WHERE clause. You will therefore have to full-scan them all anyway, index or no index.

Comment: @Ben the source table `tempData` only ever contains 1M rows as batches are loaded into it and the table is truncated for the next batch, so that requires no indexes. The destination table `entry` where the inserts go does require indexes as also the source table is joined onto it, and those joins need to reference indexes.

Comment: It all seams to be about a corrupt table, the index on the keyword table seams to be bananas, an my sql dose not even let me drop the table..

Comment: @Ben table-scanning `tempData` is accepted, table-scanning `entry` is not